# Adding directory and subdirectories to Path variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7-x64

I have a directory with many subdirectories and inside of each subdirectory I have executable files. I have them in separate subdirectories to keep them organized.

I wanna be able to call each executable in every subdirectory within the directory (already added to the system path variable) from CMD. On my search, I came across the following script from SuperUser:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D %~dp0

for /R %%G in (".") do (
    set "_dir=!dir!;%%G"
)

path=%path%!dir!
(endlocal
    set "ret=%PATH%"
)
cmd /K "title [#] Path Fixed [#] && path %ret%"
exit /B
```

In theory, I should be able to place that script in the directory, call the script in CMD and be able to call any executable within the directory/subdirectory, but it doesn't work in Windows 7 nor Windows 10.

If any of you guys could help me fixing the script or if you have a better script, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Please read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Doesn't work is not a valid problem statement and there aren't any questions in your title or message body.  What exactly do you expect it to do?  How are you using it?

Comment: You do realize that there is a limit to the length of the PATH environment variable, yes?

Comment: Sorry jwdonahue, this is my first time posting. Alright so I would like to launch cmd and be able to call any of those executable without having to type or go into each subdirectory, just the same way to can call any cmd command.

Answer (score 1):

This adds only directories that have executable content in them, to the path variable, sets the console window title and launches cmd /k with whatever arguments you start it with.  When you exit the child, the entire environment and console title are restored.

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@rem @set prompt=$G

@rem If we have any arguments, we'll pass them along to the child cmd instance.
@set _childCmd=%*

@rem Add any executable extensions you have mapped on your system that aren't
@rem listed in your PATHEXT variable.
@rem On my Win10, PATHEXT has: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
set _executables=*.ps *.py

@rem Add PATHEXT contents, replacing semicolons with spaces and dots with *.
set _tmp=%PATHEXT:;= %
set _tmp=%_tmp:.=*.%
set _executables=%_executables% %_tmp%

@rem It's ok if the caller clears the path first.
@set _path=%path%
@rem Find all the executables in and below the current directory and add to path.
@for /f %%G in ('dir /b /s %_executables%') do @call :AddToPathOnlyOnce "%%~dpG"
@set "path=%_path%"

@rem Clean-up a bit before launching into new cmd instance.
@set _path=
@set _tmp=
@set _executables=

@rem Set title and launch new instance.
@title Command Prompt (extended path)
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set _childCmd=& @call cmd.exe /K %_childCmd%
@endlocal

@rem Title is not recovered on endlocal, so restore it before exiting script.
@title Command Prompt
@endlocal
@exit /b 0

:AddToPathOnlyOnce
@set _tmp=%~1
@if not defined _path (@set "_path=%_tmp%" & @exit /b 0)
@rem If it's already in the path, remove it and then add to the end.
@set "_path=!_path:%_tmp%=!"
@set "_path=%_path:;;=%"
@set "_path=%_path%;%_tmp%"
@exit /b 0
```

I always use the `@` prefix everywhere, except the lines I am debugging, rather than setting echo off within the script, because it doesn't compose well with other scripts. In this case, you want whatever the callers setting was when you switch to the child instance anyway.

Remove the `rem` statement from the `@rem @set prompt=$G`line if you need to debug this script for any reason.

Note there are no multi-line blocks anywhere in the script (I always avoid them wherever possible), but we still need `EnableDelayedExpansion` in one of the `set` commands.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.

Comment: Also, it doesn't' have to be the same or similar to that script, if you have a better way/script to get it done, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /D %~dp0

for /R %%G in (".") do (
    set "_dir=!dir!;%%G"
)

SET path=%path%!dir!
(endlocal
    set "ret=%PATH%"
)
cmd /K "title [#] Path Fixed [#] && SET path=%ret%"
exit /B
```

should, I believe, work (I haven't used `cmd /k` in 20+ years of working with NT-style batch)

Comment: Magoo, I didn't write that script, I though it was just simple enough.